# How should I migrate a zfs pool to Windows Storage Spaces?

Tags: zfs, migration, truenas, refs, windows-storage-server

I have a single hard drive that I want to migrate to Windows Storage Spaces ReFS file system for better Windows compatibility. Obviously copying all the data to another disk and back is a last resort; so, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to migrate from a given filesystem to a different one/different storage, regardless of the filesystem type is to physically copy all the files. ZFS is no exception from this rule.

There's no conversion tools.